# Adding information to points

Tags: qgis, point

New to QGIS here.  I'm trying to figure out how to add information to set points.  I'm trying to use them as leads, so I can put lead name, address, phone number, whether they've been talked to, etc. How exactly would I go about doing that?

Comment: This is very basic. Maybe you should work through the [documentation/tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/index.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing attribute table in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234709/editing-attribute-table-in-qgis)

Comment: A vector layer is like a table. Each row of that table is a feature. In one column of that table is stored a geometry. Initially, we can assume that each rendered point represents the geometry value of each feature of the layer. Other columns can have texts, numbers, dates, etc. So, for each feature (row) of the layer (table), you have a geometry and you can have other attributes. Geometries are rendered in the map, and other attributes are showed in the attributes table associated with the layer. With that information you can take the manual and start walking you way in GIS. You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have these 2 options:

1) You can add all these attributes during the creation of your point file

2) You can add attributes (your layer must be in editing mode) in the attribute table view

Comment: Ok neat, how to set it up so it displays it on hover over?

Comment: Found it, identify features.

Comment: Or use the Map Tips feature.